# BS4, getting exact match between unclosed <br>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<tbody id="plaintiff-body">
   <tr>
      <td><img id="plaimg0001" src="/CaseInformationOnline/images/minus.png" onclick="showhide('pladetail0001','','plaimg0001')"></td>
      <td>JENEE BENNETT</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>COURTNEY L HANNA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="pladetail0001" style="" valign="top">
      <td></td>
      <td>2348 WOODBROOK CIR N<br>UNIT D<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43223</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>JOSEPH &amp; JOSEPH CO LPA   <br>SUITE 200<br>155 W MAIN ST<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282<br><br>DEBORAH L MCNINCH<br>JOSEPH &amp; JOSEPH CO LPA   <br>THE WATERFORD, SUITE 200 <br>155 W MAIN ST<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282<br><br>S K DODDERER<br>155 W MAIN STREET<br>#200<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
att = [x.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for x in soup.select(
    '#plaintiff-body tr:first-child > td:nth-child(4), #plaintiff-body tr:nth-child(2) > td:last-child')]
print(att)
```

Current output:

```
['COURTNEY L HANNA', 'JOSEPH & JOSEPH CO LPA SUITE 200 155 W MAIN ST COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282 DEBORAH L MCNINCH JOSEPH & JOSEPH CO LPA THE WATERFORD, SUITE 200 155 W MAIN ST COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282 S K DODDERER 155 W MAIN STREET #200 COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282']
```

Desired Output:

```
['COURTNEY L HANNA', 'JOSEPH & JOSEPH CO LPA SUITE 200 155 W MAIN ST COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282']
```

How to achieve that ?

I'm thinking to use https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function to pass a function and loop overn the match and once i found `br` empty then i will stop the loop.

Otherwise i can get `x` itself instead of `x.get_text()` and then split on `><` to get the first index and then use https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html?highlight=remove#w3lib.html.remove_tags

Happy to know if there a direct solution with `CSS` or a simple one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another version:

```py
import re

for br in soup.select("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")

out = [
    re.sub(r"\s{2,}|\n", " ", td.text.split("\n\n")[0])
    for td in soup.select("td:last-child")
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['COURTNEY L HANNA', 'JOSEPH & JOSEPH CO LPA SUITE 200 155 W MAIN ST COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282']
```

---

With:

```py
html = '''<tbody id="plaintiff-body">
                <tr><td><img id="plaimg0001" src="/CaseInformationOnline/images/minus.png" onclick="showhide('pladetail0001','','plaimg0001')"></td><td>TIMOTHY MOORE</td><td></td><td>TIMOTHY MOORE</td></tr><tr id="pladetail0001" style="" valign="top"><td></td><td>62 KEENE DRIVE<br>WESTERVILLE, OH 43081</td><td></td><td>62 KEENE DRIVE<br>WESTERVILLE, OH 43081</td></tr>
                </tbody>'''
```

Prints:

```py
['TIMOTHY MOORE', '62 KEENE DRIVE WESTERVILLE, OH 43081']
```

---

With:

```py
html = '''<tbody id="plaintiff-body">
                <tr><td><img id="plaimg0001" src="/CaseInformationOnline/images/minus.png" onclick="showhide('pladetail0001','','plaimg0001')"></td><td>CENA PEDRO</td><td></td><td>ELIZABETH R WERNER</td></tr><tr id="pladetail0001" style="" valign="top"><td></td><td>33 W WEISHEIMER RD<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215</td><td></td><td>THE NIGH LAW GROUP, LLC  <br>300 S. 2ND STREET<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 379-6444<br><br>JOSEPH A NIGH<br>THE NIGH LAW GROUP, LLC  <br>300 S. 2ND STREET<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 379-6444</td></tr>
                </tbody>'''
```

Prints:

```py
['ELIZABETH R WERNER', 'THE NIGH LAW GROUP, LLC 300 S. 2ND STREET COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 379-6444']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stop if two `<br>` tags are found:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tds = soup.select('#plaintiff-body tr:first-child > td:nth-child(4), #plaintiff-body tr:nth-child(2) > td:last-child')
output = []

for td in tds:
    entry = []
    last_el = None
    
    for el in td.descendants:
        if el.name == 'br':
            if last_el.name == 'br':
                break
        else:
            entry.append(el.get_text(strip=True))
        
        last_el = el
        
    output.append(' '.join(entry))
    
print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, that’s will not be ideal in case if address length changes since I’m dealing with different length of addresses

Comment: The 5 is the number of parts (not characters), you would need to give some extra examples of where it would break

Comment: Something like [that](https://bpa.st/RFAA) would break

Comment: Agreed, best to stop after two actual <br> tags, I have added an alternative

Answer (score 0):

> Happy to know if there a direct solution with CSS ...

Main issue here is that sibling combinators `br+br` in `CSS` ignore all non-element nodes between elements including comments, text and whitespace, so as far as `CSS` is concerned, you wont get the two consecutive to go from there.

So your idea with a function to check for the tags would also be my approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<tbody id="plaintiff-body">
   <tr>
      <td><img id="plaimg0001" src="/CaseInformationOnline/images/minus.png" onclick="showhide('pladetail0001','','plaimg0001')"></td>
      <td>JENEE BENNETT</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>COURTNEY L HANNA</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="pladetail0001" style="" valign="top">
      <td></td>
      <td>2348 WOODBROOK CIR N<br>UNIT D<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43223</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>JOSEPH &amp; JOSEPH CO LPA   <br>SUITE 200<br>155 W MAIN ST<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282<br><br>DEBORAH L MCNINCH<br>JOSEPH &amp; JOSEPH CO LPA   <br>THE WATERFORD, SUITE 200 <br>155 W MAIN ST<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282<br><br>S K DODDERER<br>155 W MAIN STREET<br>#200<br>COLUMBUS, OH 43215<br>(614) 449-8282</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

def check(x):
    s = []
    for a,b in zip(x,x[1::]):
        if a==b:
            break
        if a.name == None:
            s.append(a.text.strip())
    return ' '.join(s)

att = [check(x.contents) if len(x.contents) > 1 else x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('#plaintiff-body tr:first-child > td:nth-child(4), #plaintiff-body tr:nth-child(2) > td:last-child')]
print(att)
```

##### Output

```
['COURTNEY L HANNA', 'JOSEPH & JOSEPH CO LPA SUITE 200 155 W MAIN ST COLUMBUS, OH 43215 (614) 449-8282']
```

Comment: Noticed it's will give incorrect output in this case -->https://bpa.st/VQIA